# ASCII Strings and Zero-Allocation

Tags: c#, performance, strings

Over the weekend [this article](https://blog.ikeran.org/?p=284) inspired me to write an ASCII string implementation that avoids memory allocation during basic operations like `Substring` and `Trim`. It's still a work-in-progress but I think this is a solid foundation to build off of and wanted some help checking my logic/maths.

The main method of interest is the overload of `Substring` that accepts an offset and a count since most other methods are implemented by calling it.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ByteTerrace.CSharp.Data
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents text as a series of ASCII characters.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Inspired by Christopher Wright's FastString work: https://github.com/dhasenan/FastString.
    /// </remarks>
    public struct AsciiString : IEquatable<AsciiString>
    {
        private readonly ArraySegment<byte> m_bytes;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the <see cref="char"/> object at a specified position in this <see cref="AsciiString"/> instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="index">A position in the current string.</param>
        public char this[int index] {
            get {
                if ((index < 0) || ((m_bytes.Offset + index) > (m_bytes.Offset + Length))) {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
                }

                return (char)m_bytes.Array[m_bytes.Offset + index];
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates whether this <see cref="AsciiString"/> instance is empty.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsEmpty {
            get {
                return m_bytes.Count == 0;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates whether this <see cref="AsciiString"/> instance is empty or consists of only whitespace characters.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsEmptyOrWhitespace {
            get {
                return Trim().IsEmpty;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// The number of characters in this <see cref="AsciiString"/> instance.
        /// </summary>
        public int Length {
            get {
                return m_bytes.Count;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AsciiString"/> structure to the value indicated by an <see cref="Array"/> of ASCII bytes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bytes">An <see cref="Array"/> of ASCII bytes.</param>
        public AsciiString(ArraySegment<byte> bytes) { m_bytes = bytes; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AsciiString"/> structure to the value indicated by an <see cref="ArraySegment{T}"/> of ASCII bytes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bytes">An <see cref="ArraySegment{T}"/> of ASCII bytes.</param>
        public AsciiString(byte[] bytes) : this(new ArraySegment<byte>(bytes ?? new byte[0])) { }
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AsciiString"/> structure to the value indicated by an <see cref="Array"/> of ASCII bytes,
        /// a starting position within that array, and a length.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bytes">An array of ASCII bytes.</param>
        /// <param name="offset">The zero-based starting character position of a substring in bytes.</param>
        /// <param name="count">The number of characters in the substring.</param>
        public AsciiString(byte[] bytes, int offset, int count) : this(new ArraySegment<byte>(bytes, offset, count)) { }
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AsciiString"/> structure to the value indicated by a <see cref="string"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">A string value that will be transcoded to ASCII.</param>
        public AsciiString(string value) : this(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value ?? string.Empty)) { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new copy of this <see cref="AsciiString"/> instance.
        /// </summary>
        public unsafe AsciiString Copy() {
            var buffer = new byte[Length];
            var count = m_bytes.Offset + Length;

            fixed (byte* leftPointer = &buffer[0])
            fixed (byte* rightPointer = &m_bytes.Array[m_bytes.Offset]) {
                byte* left = leftPointer;
                byte* right = rightPointer;

                while (31 < count) {
                    (*(long*)(left + 0)) = (*(long*)(right + 0));
                    (*(long*)(left + 8)) = (*(long*)(right + 8));
                    (*(long*)(left + 16)) = (*(long*)(right + 16));
                    (*(long*)(left + 24)) = (*(long*)(right + 24));

                    count -= 32;
                    left += 32;
                    right += 32;
                }

                if (15 < count) {
                    (*(long*)(left + 0)) = (*(long*)(right + 0));
                    (*(long*)(left + 8)) = (*(long*)(right + 8));

                    count -= 16;
                    left += 16;
                    right += 16;
                }


                while (0 < count) {
                    *left = *right;

                    count--;
                    left++;
                    right++;
                }
            }

            return new AsciiString(buffer);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether this instance and another specified <see cref="AsciiString"/> object have the same value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="other">The <see cref="AsciiString"/> to compare to this instance.</param>
        public unsafe bool Equals(AsciiString other) {
            var count = Length;

            if (count != other.Length) {
                return false;
            }
            else { // shamelessly adapted from http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,11648d2d83718c5e
                fixed (byte* leftPointer = &m_bytes.Array[m_bytes.Offset])
                fixed (byte* rightPointer = &other.m_bytes.Array[other.m_bytes.Offset]) {
                    byte* left = leftPointer;
                    byte* right = rightPointer;

                    while (31 < count) {
                        if ((*(long*)(left + 0) != *(long*)(right + 0))
                         || (*(long*)(left + 8) != *(long*)(right + 8))
                         || (*(long*)(left + 16) != *(long*)(right + 16))
                         || (*(long*)(left + 24) != *(long*)(right + 24))
                        ) { return false; }

                        count -= 32;
                        left += 32;
                        right += 32;
                    }

                    if (15 < count) {
                        if ((*(long*)(left + 0) != *(long*)(right + 0))
                         || (*(long*)(left + 8) != *(long*)(right + 8))
                        ) { return false; }

                        count -= 16;
                        left += 16;
                        right += 16;
                    }

                    while (0 < count) {
                        if (*left != *right) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        count--;
                        left++;
                        right++;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether this instance and another specified <see cref="object"/>, which also must be a <see cref="AsciiString"/>, have the same value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="other">The <see cref="object"/> to compare to this instance.</param>
        public override bool Equals(object other) {
            var asciiString = other as AsciiString?;

            if (asciiString.HasValue) {
                return Equals(asciiString.Value);
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the hash code for the underlying <see cref="ArraySegment{T}"/> of this <see cref="AsciiString"/> instance.
        /// </summary>
        public override int GetHashCode() {
            return m_bytes.GetHashCode();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves a substring from this <see cref="AsciiString"/> instance. The slice will be performed left to right and has a specified length.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="count">The number of characters in the substring.</param>
        public AsciiString SliceLeft(int count) {
            return Substring(0, count);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves a substring from this <see cref="AsciiString"/> instance. The slice will be performed right to left and has a specified length.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="count">The number of characters in the substring.</param>
        public AsciiString SliceRight(int count) {
            return Substring(Length - count, count);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves a substring from this <see cref="AsciiString"/> instance. The substring starts at a specified character position and has a specified length.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="offset">The zero-based starting character position of a substring in this instance.</param>
        /// <param name="count">The number of characters in the substring.</param>
        public AsciiString Substring(int offset, int count) {
            if ((offset < 0) || ((m_bytes.Offset + offset + count) > (m_bytes.Offset + Length))) {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(offset));
            }
            if (count > m_bytes.Count) {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));
            }

            return new AsciiString(m_bytes.Array, m_bytes.Offset + offset, count);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves a substring from this <see cref="AsciiString"/> instance. The substring starts at a specified character position and continues to the end of the string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="offset">The zero-based starting character position of a substring in this instance.</param>
        public AsciiString Substring(int offset) {
            return Substring(offset, Length - offset);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts this <see cref="AsciiString"/> value to its equivalent <see cref="string"/> representation.
        /// </summary>
        public override string ToString() {
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(m_bytes.Array, m_bytes.Offset, m_bytes.Count);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Removes all leading whitespace characters from this <see cref="AsciiString"/> instance.
        /// </summary>
        public AsciiString TrimLeft() {
            var index = m_bytes.Offset;
            var count = Length;

            while (0 < count--) {
                if (!IsWhitespaceCharacter(m_bytes, index++)) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return SliceRight(++count);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Removes all trailing whitespace characters from this <see cref="AsciiString"/> instance.
        /// </summary>
        public AsciiString TrimRight() {
            var index = Length - 1;
            var count = Length;

            while (0 < count--) {
                if (!IsWhitespaceCharacter(m_bytes, index--)) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return SliceLeft(++count);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Removes all leading and trailing whitespace characters from this <see cref="AsciiString"/> instance.
        /// </summary>
        public AsciiString Trim() {
            return TrimLeft().TrimRight();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether two <see cref="AsciiString"/> objects have the same value.
        /// </summary>
        public static bool operator ==(AsciiString left, AsciiString right) {
            return left.Equals(right);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether two <see cref="AsciiString"/> objects have different values.
        /// </summary>
        public static bool operator !=(AsciiString left, AsciiString right) {
            return !left.Equals(right);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AsciiString"/> structure to the value indicated by an <see cref="Array"/> of ASCII bytes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bytes">An <see cref="Array"/> of ASCII bytes.</param>
        public static implicit operator AsciiString(byte[] bytes) {
            return new AsciiString(bytes);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AsciiString"/> structure to the value indicated by an <see cref="ArraySegment{T}"/> of ASCII bytes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bytes">An <see cref="ArraySegment{T}"/> of ASCII bytes.</param>
        public static implicit operator AsciiString(ArraySegment<byte> bytes) {
            return new AsciiString(bytes);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AsciiString"/> structure to the value indicated by a <see cref="string"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">A string value that will be transcoded to ASCII.</param>
        public static implicit operator AsciiString(string value) {
            return new AsciiString(value);
        }

        private static bool IsWhitespaceCharacter(ArraySegment<byte> bytes, int index) {
            var c = bytes.Array[bytes.Offset + index];

            if ((c == 0x20) || ((c > 0x08) && (c < 0x0E))) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I must say I like this solution much better then the _original one_ with its weird `Splitter`, `Slicer` and what not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> public AsciiString Substring(int offset, int count) {
>     if ((offset < 0) || ((m_bytes.Offset + offset + count) > (m_bytes.Offset + Length))) {
>         throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(offset));
>     }
>     if (count > m_bytes.Count) {
>         throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));
>     }
>
>     return new AsciiString(m_bytes.Array, m_bytes.Offset + offset, count);
> }
> ```

If we take a look at the first `if` statement we can simplify `((m_bytes.Offset + offset + count) > (m_bytes.Offset + Length))` to `((offset + count) > Length)`.

If we assume `Length == 10` and we call

> ```
> public AsciiString Substring(int offset) {
>     return Substring(offset, Length - offset);
> }
> ```

with `offset == 11` the overloaded `Substring(int, int)` will be called like `Substring(11, -1)` which just passes the `if` conditions but will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` at calling the constructor of the `ArraySegment` which means you are exposing implementation details.

Another edge case is if `offset == Length`, using the above example with `Length == 10`, which would result in `Substring(10, 0)` which shouldn't be valid either.

If you change the second `if` to

```
if (count < 1 || count > m_bytes.Count) {
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));
}
```

this should be fixed.

---

For the constructors the points about validation and exposing implementation details apply as well. Although the overloaded constructors are looking nice, some validation should take place.

At least for `public AsciiString(byte[] bytes, int offset, int count)` the passed arguments should be validated.

---

The `IsWhitespaceCharacter()` method could be simplified by just returning the condition of the `if`. Although I don't know how the compiler will optimize it I would suggest to switch the conditions on the right hand side of the `||` operator. This is because more characters will be `> 0x08` than `< 0x0E`.

```
private static bool IsWhitespaceCharacter(ArraySegment<byte> bytes, int index) {
    var c = bytes.Array[bytes.Offset + index];
    return (c == 0x20) || ((c < 0x0E) && (c > 0x08);
}
```

---

The `IsEmptyOrWhiteSpace()` method could be improved some more by first checking for `IsEmpty` and introducing a `IsWhytespace()` method which simply checks for whitespace characters.

```
public bool IsEmptyOrWhitespace
{
    get
    {
        return IsEmpty || IsWhitespace();
    }
}
private bool IsWhitespace()
{
    byte[] current = new byte[m_bytes.Count - m_bytes.Offset];
    Array.Copy(m_bytes.Array, current, current.Length);

   return current.All(c => (c == 0x20) || ((c < 0x0E) && (c > 0x08));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> public AsciiString(byte[] bytes) : this(new ArraySegment<byte>(bytes ?? new byte[0])) { }
> ```

I find you shouldn't allow nulls but if you do, then it's better to provide a default constructor (or in a case of a sctruct it already has one) then doing as everything was fine. This might not crash because of this but it might hide a bug that is hard to find because the user might have done something wrong where his bytes are null but actually shouldn't. He expects a new `AsciiString` is created from his buffer but in reality it just did some weird initialization from an empty one.

> ```
> public AsciiString(string value) : this(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value ?? string.Empty)) { }
> ```

The same here. I'd be really surprised if I passed an invalid string and it actually *worked*.

---

> ```
> public struct AsciiString
> ```

I think it should be a class rather then a struct. What happens to the buffers when you pass an `AsciiString` via a parameter? Are they copied too? I think this kills the whole *fast-string* idea.

Comment: Am experimenting with the idea that null and the empty string are equivalent; one can opt out of this decision by wrapping an `AsciiString` in a `Nullable<>` to intercept the constructors. As for the copying, no. The current design is intended for maximum performance and doesn't protect the programmer outside of simple bounds checking. The `Copy` method allocates an entirely new array if one needs a buffer that no one can manipulate without resorting to naughty things.

Comment: `AsciiString`s take up half the size of standard .NET strings which inherently makes them faster during most operations (unless I personally failed to optimize a function well enough). Even if I choose to give up the zero allocation feature they'd still be half the size and thus allocating them is twice as fast. I have confirmed this in testing with `Copy` and `Equals`.